# How to create a file that just consist of ones

Tags: linux

To create a binary file with all '0's, one could do

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=foo bs=1024 count=1
```

What if I wanted to create a file with all '1's? I can't find `/dev/one` anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such virtual device as `/dev/one`. You can replace the `NUL` character that you receive from `/dev/zero` though:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1 | tr '\000' '1' > foo
```

Replace `'1'` with whatever you need instead. The `'1'` will result in hexadecimal `31`, so the "standard" 1, which could also be written as octal `\061`. You can use octal notation in `tr` by prepending with `\`, like with `\000`.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to create a file with binary 1s the following will work:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1024 | tr "\000" "\377" > foo
```